# MySQL - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery

Tags: mysql

This is the `php` code what I'm using

```
    $Last_Video         = $db->fetch_all('
    SELECT VID, thumb
    FROM video
    WHERE VID IN (
        SELECT VID
        FROM video
        WHERE title LIKE "%'.$Channel['name'].'%"
        ORDER BY viewtime DESC
        LIMIT 5)
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
');
```

This is the error what give me

```
 Message:   Error during SQL execution: SELECT VID, thumb FROM video WHERE VID IN ( SELECT VID FROM video WHERE title LIKE "%funny%" ORDER BY viewtime DESC LIMIT 5) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1<br />
 MySQL Error:   This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'<br />
MySQL Errno:    1235
```

Comment: how i can fix this lol ... or how i can make it working ...

Comment: Use a version of MySQL that supports it?

Comment: Can you please supply the whole code. How is $db set for example?

Comment: 5.1.59 this is the version what i use

Comment: Still the case with 5.7.11

Comment: Still the case with 8.0.13 !

Comment: Maria DB also not supported this in subquery.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Instead of using IN, you can use JOIN

```
SELECT v.VID, v.thumb
FROM video AS v
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT VID
     FROM video
     WHERE title LIKE "%'.$Channel['name'].'%"
     ORDER BY viewtime DESC
     LIMIT 5) as v2
  ON v.VID = v2.VID
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: i try this code and works perfect ... this is the way how i use it     $Last_Video         = $db->fetch_all('SELECT v.VID, v.thumb FROM video AS v INNER JOIN (SELECT VID FROM video WHERE title LIKE "%'.$Channel['name'].'%" ORDER BY viewtime DESC LIMIT 5) as v2 ON v.VID = v2.VID ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
   
    foreach($Last_Video as $Video) {
     $Array              = array(
      "VID"               => $Video['VID'],
      "Thumb"             => $Video['thumb'],
      "Total_Videos2"     => $Total_Videos['num'],
      "Last_Update_Data"  => time()
     );

Comment: parameters should be used to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 177):

You can use below to bypass this error.

```
$Last_Video = $db->fetch_all('
    SELECT VID, thumb
    FROM video
    WHERE VID IN (select * from (
        SELECT VID
        FROM video
        WHERE title LIKE "%'.$Channel['name'].'%"
        ORDER BY viewtime DESC
        LIMIT 5) temp_tab)
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
');
```

Comment: not sure why the db engine can't accommodate something like this without the need to wrap a subquery in a subquery - which just seems stupid.  but hey, this works so thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work if you are trying to reference outer select statement column from inner select stament.  Example:  `select p1.categoryid, p1.productid from products p1 WHERE p1.productid IN (select * from (select p2.productid from products p2 WHERE p2.categoryid=p1.categoryid order by p2.categoryid asc, p2.unitprice desc limit 3) as tabelka);`

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a subquery here. Try this:

```
 SELECT VID, thumb
 FROM video
 WHERE title LIKE "%'.$Channel['name'].'%"
 ORDER BY RAND() DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

In MySQL 5.0.26 and later, you will get an error:

> MySQL does not support LIMIT in subqueries for certain subquery operators:

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html).

Comment: That doesn't meet the original goal of selecting one record at random for the 5 returned from subquery.

Comment: The edit still does not support the ability to limit the random selection to only those records with 5 highest values for `viewtime`

Answer (score 4):

add this is your in condition

```sql
(SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
) sub
ORDER BY id ASC)
```

Comment: Why, what do you get with this?

Comment: apparently the db engine can't handle a limit in a subquery, but does in a subquery in a subquery. Now we not only have to deal with sql injection, but also sql inception...

Comment: I'm surprised this didn't get more upvotes. I mean it seems stupid that this is a solution, but we can blame MySQL for that. This is a quick and easy solution for anyone trying to get their query working.

Comment: I ... I ... I can't ... Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you cant use simple: ?

```
SELECT v.VID, v.thumb
FROM video as v
WHERE title LIKE "%'.$Channel['name'].'%"
ORDER BY viewtime DESC
LIMIT 5
```

what for subqueries here?

Comment: Because your query doesn't accomplish what he is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

mysql is disabled **read it ORACLE**

DELETE FROM wall_orders WHERE order_id IN (
SELECT order_id FROM (SELECT order_id, COUNT(orders_products_id) as cnt FROM `wall_orders_products` GROUP BY order_id ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1000) y1 WHERE cnt > 170 LIMIT 1000)

> 235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Simple SQL and not possible