# how can i use LIMIT operator in subquery with IN operator in outer query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

my query is like

```
SELECT e.emp_name, d.dept_name, s.salary
FROM employes e
JOIN departments d
ON e.dept_id = d.dept_id
JOIN salary s
ON e.emp_id = s.emp_id
AND e.emp_id NOT IN (SELECT emp_id
    FROM salary s
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    LIMIT 2)
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1
```

and i am getting this error...

```
[Err] 1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu)

Comment: i already visited that link but unable to understand.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT e.emp_name, d.dept_name, s.salary
FROM employes e JOIN
     departments d
     ON e.dept_id = d.dept_id JOIN
     salary s
     ON e.emp_id = s.emp_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT emp_id
      FROM salary s
      ORDER BY salary DESC
      LIMIT 2
     ) s2
     on e.emp_id = s2.emp_id
WHERE s2.emp_id IS NULL
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @salmannizamani . . . It is simply a MySQL limitation.  To be honest, I don't understand the reasons why.