# SELECT ID FROM subquery with limit 1000 rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want to select 1000 rows from another table using the last 1000 ID from another table. This is the query but it returned an error message. What did I do wrong with this query?

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id IN
(
SELECT id FROM table2
LIMIT 50
)
```

Error message received.

```
Error Code : 1235
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu)

Comment: In any case, in the absence of an ORDER BY clasue, LIMIT is pretty much meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id FROM table2 ORDER BY id LIMIT 50 ) y
    ON y.id = x.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should join both tables and sort in descending order and *then* apply the limit.

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1
 JOIN table2 USING (id)
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 1000;
```

This will give you 1000 entries with highest `id`in descending order if, and only if, they exist in both tables.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure I follow. I understood that he is after the 1000 rows which a) have highest ID in table2 b) have corresponding row in table1. I changed the result set to only include rows from table1.

Comment: Hm, fair enough - your logic may in fact be better than mine. Apologies.

Answer (score -2):

It is easier to do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL1, TBL2 
WHERE TBL2.FK_ID = TBL1.ID 
ORDER BY TBL2.ID
    ASC LIMIT 0,1000
```

you can only do it if the second table has table1's id as a foreign key, but still has its own id identifying the order of when they are created.

Not sure about how to use the limit though.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I can see nothing helpful (or even true)  here.