# MYSQL: greatest-n-per-group issue

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Problem of `greatest-n-per-group` and my MySQL version cannot use the LIMIT & IN (error 1235), so I need to use this kind of query (see answer here: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu) )

```
SELECT
                t1.idMemberCard,
                DATE(MIN(transactions.dateTransaction)) AS first_transaction,
                DATE(MAX(transactions.dateTransaction)) AS last_transaction,
                t2.*
                FROM membersCard AS t1
                INNER JOIN transactions ON transactions.idMemberCard = t1.idMemberCard
                INNER JOIN
                (
                    SELECT
                        membersCard.idMemberCard,
                        membersCard.cardNumber,
                        membersCard.firstNameMemberCard,
                        membersCard.lastNameMemberCard,
                        transactions.dateTransaction
                    FROM membersCard
                    INNER JOIN transactions ON transactions.idMemberCard = membersCard.idMemberCard
                    WHERE membersCard.sexMemberCard = 'M'
                    AND membersCard.cardNumber = '1100101308655'
                    AND
                    DATE(transactions.dateTransaction) BETWEEN ('2013-12-28') AND ('2014-08-13')
                    LIMIT 100
                ) AS t2
                ON t1.idMemberCard = t2.idMemberCard
```

Subquery (t2 table) executed for exact match (card Number) returns exactly 5 rows (in this example): all perfect.

My issue/request:

Joining the two tables I would to obtain 5 rows and not only one, with the different 5 rows with the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Your `join` is working fine.  The problem is your `select` statement:

```
 SELECT t1.idMemberCard,
        DATE(MIN(transactions.dateTransaction)) AS first_transaction,
        DATE(MAX(transactions.dateTransaction)) AS last_transaction,
        t2.*
```

The use of `MIN()` and `MAX()` turn this into an aggregation query that returns only one row.  Try this:

```
 SELECT t1.idMemberCard,
        DATE(transactions.dateTransaction) AS first_transaction,
        DATE(transactions.dateTransaction) AS last_transaction,
        t2.*
```

Or add a `group by` clause if you want that.

Comment: @sineverba . . . Then add the appropriate `group by`.

Comment: If I add "GROUP BY " t1.idMemberCard (same with t2.idMemberCard) I obtain only 1 row. I need 5 rows for the cardNumber "1100101308655"