# Is there any way to make this code more efficient?..can't directly use IN coz version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Link that i referred to -> [MySQL - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu)

I have a teacher that has a code and a mac address attached to the router.. the students have to enter the same code from the same mac address.. i want a list of students who have done it ... and i want to only check the last code uploaded by the teacher

thank you for all the help :)

My code(which is working)->

```
SELECT s.s_id
FROM students s
WHERE s.mac IN
    (SELECT *
     FROM
       (SELECT t.mac
        FROM teacher t
        ORDER BY t.sno DESC
        LIMIT 1)temp_tab)
  AND s.code IN
    (SELECT *
     FROM
       (SELECT t.code
        FROM teacher t
        ORDER BY t.sno DESC
        LIMIT 1)temp_tab);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? An example would be very helpful.

Comment: I have a teacher that uploads a code and a mac address attached to the router.. the students have to enter the same code from the same mac address.. i want a list of students who have done it ... and i want to only check the last code uploaded by the teacher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a join should be more efficient, but then again, it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

```
SELECT s.s_id
FROM students s
JOIN (
    SELECT t.mac, t.code
    FROM teacher t
    ORDER BY t.sno DESC
    LIMIT 1
) t ON s.mac = t.mac AND s.code = t.code
```

Indexing the matching or ordering columns would increase the performance too.

Comment: I have a teacher that uploades a code and a mac address attached to the router.. the students have to enter the same code from the same mac address.. i want a list of students who have done it ... and i want to only check the last code uploaded by the teacher

Answer (score 0):

You can use `limit 1` with `=`:

```
SELECT s.s_id
FROM students s
WHERE s.mac = (SELECT t.mac
               FROM teacher t
               ORDER BY t.sno DESC
               LIMIT 1
              ) AND
     s.code = (SELECT t.code
               FROM teacher t
               ORDER BY t.sno DESC
               LIMIT 1
              );
```

However, this code is probably not what you want.  It is fine if there are no ties for `t.sno`.  But if they are the two fields may not come from the same row.  So, do it in one subquery:

```
SELECT s.s_id
FROM students s
WHERE (s.mac, s.code) = (SELECT t.mac, t.code
                         FROM teacher t
                         ORDER BY t.sno DESC
                         LIMIT 1
                        );
```

You can, of course, turn this into a `JOIN` as Viliam suggests.

Answer (score 0):

**instead of select s.s_id it should be *
Thanks Gordon and Villiam**

SELECT *
FROM students s
JOIN (
    SELECT t.mac, t.code
    FROM teacher t
    ORDER BY t.sno DESC
    LIMIT 1
) t ON s.mac = t.mac AND s.code = t.code

Answer (score 0):

Why does everyone think they have to run every SQL task in a single query?

Here's a much easier solution:

```
SELECT t.mac, t.code
FROM teacher t
ORDER BY t.sno DESC
LIMIT 1
INTO @mac, @code;

SELECT s.s_id
FROM students s
WHERE s.mac = @mac AND s.code = @code;
```