# MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql

While I am running this query

```
SELECT * FROM 
tb_emp_daily_status d 
where 
d.shiftdate>='2017-06-07' and 
shiftdate<='2017-06-13' and 
emp_id in (SELECT id FROM tb_employee e WHERE e.user_id = '18145' LIMIT 20) 
order by d.id asc
```

How to write this query in mysql

Comment: what's the error you're getting ?

Comment: Irrelevant: without `ORDER BY` your subquery looks weird.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT * FROM 
    tb_emp_daily_status d 
    where 
    d.shiftdate>='2017-06-07' and 
    shiftdate<='2017-06-13' and 
    emp_id in (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM tb_employee e WHERE e.user_id = '18145' LIMIT 20)   
          as t)
    order by d.id asc
```

Comment: I don't get why your solution is working but it still saves my day. Thanks.

Comment: @Lily I don't get how it works either, but it works, and saved my day too. Thank you too.

Comment: This doesn't work when you need to join the subquery to a column in the outer query: This wont work:   emp_id in (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM tb_employee e WHERE e.user_id = d.user_id LIMIT 20)   
          as t)

Answer (score 1):

instead of an IN subselect you can use ever a join with the a subselect result

```
  SELECT * FROM 
  tb_emp_daily_status d 
  INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT id FROM tb_employee e WHERE e.user_id = '18145' LIMIT 20
  ) t on d.emp_id = t.id
  where d.shiftdate>='2017-06-07' and 
  shiftdate<='2017-06-13' and 
  order by d.id asc
```

Comment: Are there any performance consequences to doing a join on this temporary table compared to [Whencesoever's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44517513/1473320)?

Comment: @kashev the join should produce a better performance respect the 0 in clause based on subquery ..  because the  in clause result is processed  server time one  time for each value . The join clause is execute just one time for all the result