# LIMIT row with LEFT join

Tags: mysql, join, limit

I have 'post' and 'comment' table. I want select **last 3 post** and **all comments for that** posts. Curently I use 2 separate statments:

```
SELECT p.* FROM post p ORDER BY p.date DESC LIMIT 3; // called 1
SELECT c.* FROM comment c WHERE c.post_id = :id; // called 3x time for each post.
```

It's possible to marge this queries into one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery for the set of posts:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT p.*
      FROM post p
      ORDER BY p.date DESC
      LIMIT 3
     ) p JOIN
     comment c
     ON c.post_id = p.id
ORDER BY p.id, c.id;
```

Comment: Works, without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   POST .*, COMMENT.* 
from POST INNER JOIN COMMENT ON POST.id = COMMENT.post_id
where  POST.id = COMMENT.post_id ORDER BY POST.id  LIMIT 3
```

Comment: This will not work. No matter what, we always get only 3 record.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
SELECT p . * , c . * 
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN 
COMMENT c ON c.post_id = p.id
where p.id IN (SELECT id from post order by date desc limit 3) ORDER BY p.date
```

Comment: Works. Your code lead me to SQL Error (1235): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'. But little search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu and problem gone. Works perfect.