# Alternative MySQL 5.6 Subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I would like to do this

First, select latest 2500 users who never login.
Second, select package and count number of users in each package.

**My SubQuery look like this**

```
select packagename, count(*) from customer where id in 
(select id from customer where lastlogin='0000-00-00 00:00:00' order by ID Desc limit 2500) 
group by packagename;
```

But I got following error

> ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &
>   IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

I am using version `5.6.11-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log`

Any alternative query that I can use wihtout upgrade MySQL ?

Comment: Have you tried the solution (a `join`, assuming your id is the primary key) provided in [MySQL - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17892762)

Comment: I'm not sure I can use join in this case becuase the main query using group by and not select any ID. So I can't join in subquery. If you can provide sample would be appriciate.

Comment: So you do not want to try it because you do not think it works? (Spoiler alert: it does work. If not, post the code you tried, as you did something wrong).

Comment: I think it work now. select packagename,count(*) from customer as c1 join (select id from customer where lastlogin='0000-00-00 00:00:00' order by ID Desc limit 2500) as c2 on c1.id=c2.id group by packagename; Thank you very much. :-)