# MYSQL DELETE with SUBQUERY gives Error code:1235

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have one table `Job_Detail_History`, which contains following structure and data:

[image]

When i try to delete query using subquery with `LIMIT`, `NOT IN`,

```
DELETE FROM job_detail_history where id not in(select id from job_detail_history order by start_time desc limit 2);
```

it's giving me :

> Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &
>   IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Then i try to find some solution over SO: 
i found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17892886/5813861) as global solution, which tells to use `JOIN` instead of `NOT IN`, but in that case they are using select query. So, the query looks like this :

```
SELECT * from job_detail_history INNER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM job_detail_history order by start_time desc limit 2) as v2 limit 2;
```

and it will result a new table as result like this :

[image]

So, my question is how to handle `DELETE` scenario in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using join you can delete as well
below is an example

```
DELETE t1,t2 FROM t1
        INNER JOIN
    t2 ON t2.ref = t1.id 
WHERE
    t1.id = 1;
```

For your case change a bit

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;  

    DELETE FROM job_detail_history where id not in
    ( select * from 
               (select id from 
                job_detail_history order by start_time desc limit 2)  
                as t1
   );
```

Comment: i'm using single table only `job detail history`. and i want to keep 2 records based on start_time desc.

Comment: you have not modified limit or IN used in query. but still it works. How? because error code 1235 display "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN"

Comment: @yash support but in different way like experts suggest just use a layer upon it then use limit and in it will works