# MariaDB Query using IN with LIMIT by row

Tags: mysql, subquery, mariadb, limit, greatest-n-per-group

I am having some difficulty trying to use LIMIT in one of my Sub Queries, I ran into the error

```
MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT in subquery'
```

On a query that is similair to what I've done in PostgreSQL in order to get 3 child results for every parent that has a child

```
select * from parent
join child on child.ch_pa_id = parent.pa_id
and child.ch_id in (
  select child.ch_id from child
  where child.ch_id = parent.pa_id
  limit 3
)
order by parent.pa_id;
```

I saw that there was a question regarding the same thing here

[MySQL - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu)

The question has an answer but I am unable to get it work for my needs mainly because I need to do it by row with a join, I tried to apply the same thing to my query but I'm not sure how to keep the join working

```
select * from parent as p
join (
  select * from child
  where child.ch_pa_idno = p.pa_idno # this line breaks it
  limit 3
) as c on c.ch_pa_id = p.pa_id
order by p.pa_id;
```

It's giving an error that **p.pa_idno** is an Unknown column, I'm sure I'm being an idiot and there's something clearly wrong here

*EXAMPLE*

Here is a working example done with PostgreSQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4ed4d/2. It is returning only two parent records and for each parent it is returning only 2 child records

Comment: A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` can lead to random results.

Comment: true but order doesnt matter in this case only because it's just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround from your original query:

```
SELECT * FROM parent
JOIN child ON child.ch_pa_id = parent.pa_id
AND child.ch_id IN 
  (SELECT ch_id FROM (
  SELECT child.ch_id FROM child JOIN parent
  WHERE child.ch_id = parent.pa_id
  LIMIT 3) a
)
ORDER BY parent.pa_id;
```

Retaining the original sub-query operation to extract `ch_id` from child table with `LIMIT 3` however by adding `parent` table in the join. Then perform another operation to get the sub-query result then use that for your `IN`.

**EDIT:**
I've got a working query but I have mixed feeling about it:

```
SELECT * FROM parent 
JOIN child ON parent.pa_id=child.ch_pa_id
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT ch_pa_id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(chid,' ',1) f,SUBSTRING_INDEX(chid,' ',-1) e 
 FROM (
  SELECT ch_pa_id,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ch_id ORDER BY ch_id ASC SEPARATOR ' '),' ',3) chid 
         FROM child 
         GROUP BY ch_pa_id) a) b 
 ON child.ch_pa_id=b.ch_pa_id
WHERE child.ch_id 
BETWEEN f AND e;
```

Honestly, I'm afraid that this won't perform well in large data but I'm always learning something new and some of the function here I just discover recently.

According to your fiddle, I notice that you only take the first 3 `ch_id` for every parent. Hence, this `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ch_id ORDER BY ch_id ASC SEPARATOR ' '),' ',3) chid`. `GROUP_CONCAT` to show data horizontally and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get the first 3 `ch_id` in the assembly. Normally group_concat will return value as such; `1,2,3` and substring_index can only identify first, second and so-on value separated by [space] (' '). That's why I added `SEPARATOR ' '`.

Then I use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` twice on the outer query to define `f` and `e` whereby `SUBSTRING_INDEX(chid,' ',1)` to get the first value and `SUBSTRING_INDEX(chid,' ',-1)` to get the last value from the column. And with that I join it with the original query and added `BETWEEN f and e`.

Comment: This is close but it only gets the Parent that is linked to the Child rows returned by the Limit 3 instead of 3 Child rows for every Parent like my PostgreSQL one does

Comment: wow, that definitely does seem to work but phewww... looks complex XD

Comment: It does! I'm still trying to find a much simpler way and I'm new to MariaDB :D

Comment: Me too! PostgreSQL will always be my bae though

Answer (score 0):

Please explain, in words, the desired result.

Meanwhile, see if this gives you what you want:

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM parent AS p
    JOIN child AS c ON c.ch_pa_idno = p.pa_idno
    ORDER BY p.pa_id
    LIMIT 3
```

I am confused by `pa_`; it sounds a lot like "parent", but apparently `ch_` indicates "parent".

And what is the difference between `_id` and `_idno`?

In many implementations of parent-child (hierarchical) relations, both are in the same table.  The table has `PRIMARY KEY(id)` and a column called `parent_id`  Then a "selfjoin" is used to connect between parent and children.

It may also help if you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both `parent` and `child`.

Comment: Here is a working example done with PostgreSQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4ed4d/2, I will include it above in my question as well