# Limit in sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have made a query as below but MYSQL is returning error saying

Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

How can rewrite this query to get around this problem?

Thanks.

I tried using keyword 'IN' in the query with LIMIT 10

```
  SELECT
    'Y',
   `account`,
  `awb`,
  `hawb`,
  `service`,
  `handling`,
  `reference`,
  `date_submitted`,
  `date_imported`,
  `date_printed`,
  `printed_file_id`,
  `date_received`,
  `date_booked`,
  `booked_file_id`,
  `date_exported`,
  `export_file_id`,
  `company`,
  `contact`,
  `address_line_1`,
  `address_line_2`,
  `address_line_3`,
  `id` 
  FROM
  `consignment` WHERE `consignment`.`processed`=1 AND `eamglo5_singaporelive`.`consignment`.id NOT IN ( SELECT eamglo5_billingsystem.`consignment`.`refrence_id` FROM eamglo5_billingsystem.`consignment` limit 10) limit 10
```

Expected: Should execute the query with no problem
Actual: Getting error
Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a left join on the subquery  (instead of the IN clause) and check for not matching result

```
  SELECT
    'Y',
   `account`,
  `awb`,
  `hawb`,
  `service`,
  `handling`,
  `reference`,
  `date_submitted`,
  `date_imported`,
  `date_printed`,
  `printed_file_id`,
  `date_received`,
  `date_booked`,
  `booked_file_id`,
  `date_exported`,
  `export_file_id`,
  `company`,
  `contact`,
  `address_line_1`,
  `address_line_2`,
  `address_line_3`,
  `id` 
  FROM  `eamglo5_singaporelive`.`consignment` 
  left join  (
    SELECT eamglo5_billingsystem.`consignment`.`refrence_id` 
     FROM eamglo5_billingsystem.`consignment` 
     limit 10
  ) t  ON  t.refrence_id =`eamglo5_singaporelive`.`consignment`.id 
  WHERE `eamglo5_singaporelive`.`consignment`.`processed`=1 
  and t.refrence_id is null 
  limit 10
```

anyway a limit without order by is not a good solution

Comment: Lets say i want to bring in all rows in `eamglo5_singaporelive`.`consignment`  into eamglo5_billingsystem.`consignment` which has column 'processed'='1' and date_booked >'2018-07-17', how can i do that?

Comment: @user3855851 . . . The question in your comment seems to have nothing to do with this answer or your question.  New questions should be asked as *questions* not *comments*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57133033/mysql-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-with-specific-condition

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your query

```
slc.id NOT IN (SELECT bsc.reference_id
               FROM eamglo5_billingsystem.consignment bsc 
               LIMIT 10
              )
```

I have simplified the query by using table aliases.

First, you are using `LIMIT` with no `ORDER BY`.  This is not a good idea.

Second, in this case, the query is not correlated, so you can move it to the `FROM` clause:

```
FROM consignment c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT bsc.reference_id
      FROM eamglo5_billingsystem.consignment bsc 
      LIMIT 10
     ) bsc
     ON c.id = bsc.reference_id
WHERE c.processed = 1 AND 
      bsc.reference_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Lets say i want to bring in all rows in eamglo5_singaporelive.consignment into eamglo5_billingsystem.consignment which has column 'processed'='1' and date_booked >'2018-07-17', how can i do that?