# Solution to MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql

For some reason MYSQL doesn't support LIMIT inside a subquery:

```
 SELECT m.* 
 FROM `my_table` m
 WHERE m.`id` IN (
   SELECT o.`id`
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT i.`id`, i.`label`, i.`client`, i.`place`
     FROM `my_table` i
     ORDER BY i.`label`, -i.`client` DESC, -i.`place` DESC) o
   WHERE m.`label` = o.`label` LIMIT 1
 );
```

I've tried using join from this link: [INNER JOIN INSTEAD OF IN(LIMIT error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu/17892886) but not succeeded. Has anyone any clues for it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you share the error that your code show?

Comment: The error for the piece of code I've provided is: "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery"

Comment: Have you try to use the function [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)?

Comment: I just replaced LIMIT 1 with ROW_NUMBER() and it sill says I have errors in my query..

Comment: It is a little bit more difficult you have to use it with a `PARTITION`. Please review this [documentation](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the subquery returns only 1 row with 1 column there is no need for `IN`.
You can use `=`:

```
 SELECT m.* 
 FROM `my_table` m
 WHERE m.`id` = (
   SELECT o.`id`
   FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT i.`id`, i.`label`, i.`client`, i.`place`
     FROM `my_table` i
     ORDER BY i.`label`, -i.`client` DESC, -i.`place` DESC) o
   WHERE m.`label` = o.`label` LIMIT 1
 );
```

But as it is written, your query uses `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` (you do use `ORDER BY` in the inner subquery where it is useless).
Do you mean to do something like this:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM `my_table` m
WHERE m.`id` = (
  SELECT o.`id`
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT i.`id`, i.`label`, i.`client`, i.`place`
    FROM `my_table` i
  ) o
  WHERE m.`label` = o.`label` 
  ORDER BY o.`label`, -o.`client` DESC, -o.`place` DESC
  LIMIT 1
);
```

Also ordering by the negative value of a column descending is equivalent to ordering just ascending, so the `ORDER BY` clause can be simplified to:

```
ORDER BY o.`label`, o.`client`, o.`place`
```