# How to do mysql subquery to get random records from pre-filtered list?

Tags: php, mysql, random, subquery

I searched but couldn't find a solution that works. Need a bit help here.

Let's say I have a table with more than 100 records, first, I need to find out top 20 records in certain order, then I need to pick 5 randomly from those 20 records.
Here is my query,

```
SELECT a 
FROM tableA 
WHERE b IN (
    SELECT b 
    FROM tableA 
    WHERE c="x" 
    ORDER BY d DESC 
    LIMIT 20
) 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 5;
```

Let me know how to correct it. Thanks.

Comment: I think that query should work. Is `b` the primary key of the table?

Comment: Can you create a db-fiddle with sample data?

Comment: @Barmar b is not the primary key but still a column with unique value

Comment: Then I don't see why it doesn't work.

Comment: If it has a unique value, then it's isomorphic to the primary key, so you might as well use that.

Comment: I got the error - Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' for my query above. Not sure what that means

Comment: not sure if it matters I use prepared statement for above query

Comment: You need to join with the subquery instead of using it in `IN()`. There are hundreds of questions about that error message, did you try to search for them?

Comment: I think the query in @kristo's answer should work and doesn't have that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner query selects 20 users ordered by ID and the outer query orders by randome using the RAND() function with a limit of 5 :)

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 20
) T1
ORDER BY rand() limit 5
```

Comment: yes. this one works. I also found the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17892886/17745172 also works. Thanks!