# Laravel equivalent of a nested Query using Models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Looking for laravel equivalent of a Query.

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT * FROM tbl
   ORDER  BY updated_at
   LIMIT  20
   )
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  5;
```

Please assume we have a model class "TableA" that already exists.
Inner query can be achieved using.

```
TableA::OrderByRaw('updated_at ASC NULLS FIRST')->limit(20)->get();
```

Comment: Hi i just posted a possible answer on your last question under the marked answer comments section

Comment: One correction in it i can't edit anymore since the time limit passed `$randomRows = YourModel::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();`

Comment: Does this really work? OrderBy and inRandomOrder in same query like that? I am completely surprised.  Gotta test it.

Comment: Tbh i just wrote an equivalent, otherwise i would have to type and test code here https://laravelplayground.com/#/ hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to do this. I would prefer this way as it seems more readable.

```
<?php

$rows = TableA::whereIn('id', function($query){
        $query->select('id')
              ->from('table_a')// name of the model table
              ->orderByRaw('updated_at ASC NULLS FIRST')
              ->limit(20);
    })->orderByRaw('random()')->limit(5)->get();// use ->toSql() instead of ->get() to see the actual raw query

dd($rows);
```

**Note:** For MySQL users, you can use joins to avoid `This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &amp; IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'` error. See [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu).

---

Use a join to make the query work for both Maria DB as well as Postgres as below:

```
<?php

$subQuery = TableA::orderBy('updated_at')->limit(20);
$rows = TableA::joinSub($subQuery, 'derived_table', function($join){
         $join->on('tbl.id', '=', 'derived_table.id');
        })->inRandomOrder()->limit(5)->get();

dd($rows);
```

Refer [`Join Subquery Docs`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#subquery-joins).

Comment: That limitation on MariaDB still exists on latest version @nice_dev? Might have to redo query with join equivalent than, as I need a version compatible with both maria and postgres

Comment: @AbhishekAnand Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of hilarious, but I modified the query to below (for equivalent result).

```
SELECT *
FROM  tbl WHERE id IN (
   SELECT id FROM tbl
   ORDER  BY updated_at
   LIMIT  20
   )
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  5;
```

This version ends up taking much less db memory (for processing) and has very similar execution time.

Please note : This works in my case, as My "in" clause will never exceed 150 elements.

This can be achieved in laravel using,

```
TableA::whereIn('id', function ($query) {
                    $query->select('id')->from('tbl')
                        ->OrderByRaw('updated_at ASC NULLS FIRST')
                        ->limit(20);
                })->inRandomOrder()->limit(5);
```

Comment: helping anyone who might visit this question, if i am not wrong? so the answer marked query applies random ordering only to the 20 records obtained from the subquery and your query applies random ordering to the entire result set, which might include records beyond the initial 20 selected by the subquery